# ¿Como guardo datos en un objeto serializado?

Tags: java

Una parte del ejercicio pide lo siguiente:

> Se van solicitando los datos de los clientes y se van guardando en el archivo serializado.

**¿Como lo hago?** No entiendo si debo implementar `java.io.Serializable` en la clase donde guardo los datos o en la principal.

Tengo como pequeña referencia esto pero no entiendo muy bien como usarlo correctamente:

`FileInputStream fich = new FileInputStream(“str.out”); ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fich); Object o = os.readObject();`

Gracias de antemano.

**Editado:** He modificado algo el codigo pero sigo sin poder escribir en el archivo creado.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Principal {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String directorio = null;
        String archivo = null;



        String nombre, nif, direccion;
        int edad, telefono;



         Cliente cliente=new Cliente();


         Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Ingrese el directorio");
         directorio = teclado.nextLine();
         boolean exito = (new File(directorio)).mkdir();

         System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del archivo");
         archivo=teclado.nextLine();
         File fichero = new File(directorio, archivo);
         fichero.createNewFile();

         System.out.println("Numero de clientes que se van a guardar en el archivo");         
         Scanner read0=new Scanner(System.in); 
          int Tamaño=read0.nextInt();

    //---------Construye el Array según el tamaño definido por usuario--------//

         Cliente[] Clientes=new Cliente[Tamaño];
         Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in); //Previene el doble salto//     
         for (int i=0; i<Clientes.length;i++){
         System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre");
         nombre=read.next();
         System.out.println("Ingrese la edad");
         edad=read.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Ingrese el telefono");
         telefono=read.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Ingrese el nif");
         nif=read.next();
         System.out.println("Ingrese la direccion");
         direccion=read.next();
         Clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre,edad, telefono, nif, direccion);
         }



          for (int i=0; i<Clientes.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.println(Clientes[i].getNombre() +" "+ Clientes[i].getEdad()  );
        }



    }

    }
```

```
package Examen;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private int telefono;
    private String nif;
    private String direccion;


    public Cliente(){

    }

    public Cliente(String nombre, int edad, int telefono, String nif, String direccion){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.edad=edad;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.nif=nif;
        this.direccion=direccion;

    }

    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the edad
     */
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    /**
     * @param edad the edad to set
     */
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefono
     */
    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefono the telefono to set
     */
    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nif
     */
    public String getNif() {
        return nif;
    }

    /**
     * @param nif the nif to set
     */
    public void setNif(String nif) {
        this.nif = nif;
    }

    /**
     * @return the direccion
     */
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    /**
     * @param direccion the direccion to set
     */
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }


}
```

Quiero guardar los clientes con sus respectivos atributos por teclado en el archivo creado, por favor, no entiendo como hacerlo y me esta frustrando.

Creo que debo utilizar esto y seria algo así:

```
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);

            objectOutput.writeObject(Clientes);
            objectOutput.writeObject(Clientes);

            objectOutput.close();
            fileOutput.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Serializable** es una Interfaz de JAVA que permite convertir objetos en un montón de bytes para poder ser enviados a través de la red, socket o escribirlos en ficheros de texto.

En tu caso para que Java sepa deconstruir y construir objetos en bytes que puedan ser escritos en un fichero de texto, dicho objeto debe implementar la interfaz `Serializable`.

Es una interfaz muy sencilla sin métodos así que solo debemos implementarla en la clase en la que se definan los objetos a Serializar. En tu caso Cliente.

```
public class Cliente implements Serializable{}
```

Para saber donde debes implementarla, pregúntate siempre *¿De que clase son los objetos que voy a escribir en el fichero?* De la clase **Cliente**... por lo tanto esta debe ser **Serializable**.

Para escribir objetos en ficheros debemos instanciar objetos de las siguientes clases:

**File**: Para crear el archivo.

**FileInputStream** y **FileOutputStream**: Para leer o escribir los objetos.

**ObjectInputStream** y **ObjectOutputStream**: Encargados de manejar la lectura y escritura.

```
Cliente objeto = new Cliente(); // Por ejemplo
File file = new File("ruta");

    try {
         FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream (file);
         ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);

         oo.writeObject(objeto);

         oo.close();
         fo.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Existen formas mas simples y mas complejas que iras aprendiendo con el tiempo, usando **try-with-resources** por ejemplo o dividiendo la escritura y lectura en clases con el patron **DAO**, solo para que te suenen. Poco a poco :)

---

Tenemos la clase Cliente, que implementa la interfaz Serializable. He borrado el método datos(); pues intuyo que lo usas para crear nuevas instancias de Cliente pero para eso tienes el Constructor parametrizado.

> Cliente.java

```
package stackOverflow;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private int telefono;
    private String nif;
    private String direccion;

    public Cliente() {

    }

    public Cliente(String nombre, int edad, int telefono, String nif, String direccion) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the edad
     */
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    /**
     * @param edad the edad to set
     */
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefono
     */
    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefono the telefono to set
     */
    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nif
     */
    public String getNif() {
        return nif;
    }

    /**
     * @param nif the nif to set
     */
    public void setNif(String nif) {
        this.nif = nif;
    }

    /**
     * @return the direccion
     */
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    /**
     * @param direccion the direccion to set
     */
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

}
```

En la clase Principal.java lo que hago es crear dos nuevos Clientes, gracias al constructor parametrizado y escribir dichos clientes en el archivo de objetos. Obviaré todos los imports necesarios para ahorrar espacio el IDE debe avisarte e importar automaticamente.

> Principal.java

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //String nombre, int edad, int telefono, String nif, String direccion
        Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente("Pepe", 18, 667483734, "999999999X", "Calle Pepe");
        Cliente cliente2 = new Cliente("Pepa", 32, 667483735, "999999998X", "Calle Pepa");

        File file = new File("datos.obj");

        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);

            objectOutput.writeObject(cliente1);
            objectOutput.writeObject(cliente2);

            objectOutput.close();
            fileOutput.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

¿Que hacemos en esta clase?

1. Crear dos instancias de `Cliente()`, gracias al constructor, estos serán los que voy a escribir en el fichero.
2. Defino el objeto `File` en cuyo constructor le paso la ruta donde debe crearse el archivo `File("datos.obj");`

> Recuerda que por defecto esta ruta indica
>   `C:\\Users\nombre\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NombreProyecto\datos.obj`

3. Instanciar e inicializar los objetos `FileOutputStream` y `ObjectOutputStream`. A `FileOutputStream();` debemos pasarle el objeto **File** creado en el paso anterior. A `ObjectOutputStream();` debemos pasarle el objeto **FileOutputStream**.
4. Usamos el metodo del objeto **ObjectOutputStream** llamado `.writeObject();` para escribir un objeto en el fichero.

Si al ir al fichero intentas abrirlo con un procesador de textos, lógicamente vas a ver caracteres especiales y no vas a entender nada, en eso consiste precisamente y es una de las funciones de `Serializable`, convertir a los objetos en flujos de bytes que sean entendibles para JAVA. Para leerlos necesitaras **FileInputStream** y **ObjectInputStream**.

Comment: Gracias por responder de una manera tan clara. No logro entender como hacerlo, si fueses tan amable de hacer esta parte por mi (Se van solicitando los datos de los clientes y se van guardando en el archivo serializado) para poder ver un ejemplo en concreto bien hecho y tenerlo de referencia te lo agradecería. No logro  escribir en el archivo en cuestión que se crea.

Comment: No veo que pueda editar mi comentario así que escribo otro para aclarar donde tengo el problema, Llego a cliente.datos(); y ahí el programa pide introducir los diferentes atributos de los clientes, no entiendo como escribirlos en el archivo que se crea, me sale en blanco.

Comment: Dame 5 min y edito mi post con más ayuda.

Comment: Lo tengo mucho mas claro ahora con tu edición pero sigo teniendo dudas, me explico, yo he tratado de hacer un "contador" para que el programa te pregunte cuantos clientes vas a ingresar, cada uno con sus atributos ingresados por teclado. Tu me lo explicas con una opción fácil que es escribirlos manualmente y preferiría aprender a hacerlo como yo lo intento, si pudieses ayudarme seria estupendo. Siento ser tan pesado, pero es que no se me da esto de la programación y es algo que me interesa mucho, gracias por tu tiempo :)